# How to calculate the integral involving Gaussians?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Suppose that we are given a function $f_\theta$(x) defined as

\begin{eqnarray}
f_\theta(x):=\frac{\theta}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}}
+\frac{1-\theta}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2\sigma^2}}.
\end{eqnarray}
Here, $\sigma>0$ and $0<\theta<1$. How can we calculate the following integral?
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}dx \frac{1}{f_\theta(x)}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}f_\theta(x)\right)^2=?
\end{eqnarray}

I have tried *Mathematica* without success.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's simple

You can rewrite the integral as $\int \frac {f'(x)}{f(x)}f'(x)  \ dx$

Now integrate by parts

$f'(x) \ln |f(x)| - \int f''(x) \ln |f(x)|  \ dx$

Now integrate by parts again

$f'(x) \ln |f(x)| - \ln |f(x)| f'(x) +\ln |f(x)|$

Comment: This wouldn't work because the partial derivative is a derivative of $\theta$, not $x$.

Comment: Ohh i didn't see that

Comment: It is not simple. The given method is not correct even if the partial derivative is a derivative of $x$.